# ssh pass host fingerprint and private key without creating them as files

Tags: ssh, bash

I'm trying to invoke ssh with a custom private key and host fingerprint stored in local vars rather than in files. I would like to avoid creating temp files because if my script is killed I'll get no chance to clean them up (not even with `trap EXIT`). My current attempt is:

`ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=<(echo -n "$HOST_FINGERPRINT") -i <(echo -n "$PRIVATE_KEY")`

But the process substitution doesn't seem to work, I get:

```
Warning: Identity file /dev/fd/62 not accessible: No such file or directory.
        Host key verification failed.
```

Any alternatives to that? Thanks! I'm on Debian 10 btw.